# jQuery - Hide and show elements on click

Tags: jquery, hide, show, if-statement

I want to make a bottom bar that usually displays "Contact us" but when the bar is clicked, it will then display the contact details, clicking again will turn the bar to just saying "Contact Us" again. I tried toggle() but that then left me in situations where both the Contacts us + and the details were hidden.

I think I need an else statement, but my knowledge of jQuery is lackluster.

http://jsfiddle.net/DzYTZ/2/ (Which for some reason it's not working on)

Can anyone please help?

### Thanks

```
<div class="footer2"> 
    <a href="#" class="contactus">
        Contact Us
    </a>

    <div class="more">
        <a href="#">
            @twitterhandle
        </a>

        <a href="#">
            e-mail
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    .footer2
{
background-color: black;
margin-top: 1em;
padding-top: 1em;
padding-bottom: 1em;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
    .footer2 .contactus
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #e3e3e3;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
}
    .footer2 .contactus:hover
{
    color: white;
}
    .footer2 .more
{
    margin-left: 1em;
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline;
}
    .footer2 .more a
{
    margin-left: 2em;
    color: #e3e3e3;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    .footer2 .more a:hover
{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Please post your javascript code. Also, `.footer` does not exist in the HTML.

Comment: Here's a version of the jsfiddle that works... I fixed the selector in your jQuery to use .footer2 and changed the CSS definition of .footer2 .more removing display:inline.  http://jsfiddle.net/DzYTZ/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the complete code. A few main things prevented this from working. Your toggle selector needed a comma between the two classes. This applies the toggle to both elements. You also specified a class named `.footer` that did exist. Finally, the style for `.footer2 .more` had `display` specified twice. That's why it was showing when the page loaded. Updated sample here http://jsfiddle.net/DzYTZ/7/

```
    .footer2
    {
        background-color: black;
        margin-top: 1em;
        padding-top: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

        .footer2 .contactus
        {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            color: #e3e3e3;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline;
        }

            .footer2 .contactus:hover
            {
                color: white;
            }



        .footer2 .more
        {
            margin-left: 1em;
            display: none;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            color: #e3e3e3;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            .footer2 .more a
            {
                margin-left: 2em;
                color: #e3e3e3;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

                .footer2 .more a:hover
                {
                    display: none;
                    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                    font-weight: 400;
                    color: white;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
```

--

```
<div class="footer2">
    <a href="#" class="contactus">Contact Us
    </a>
    <div class="more">
        <a href="#">TWITTER HANDLE
        </a>

        <a href="#">EMAIL
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

--

```
    $(function () {

        $('.footer2').click(function () {

            $('.contactus, .more').toggle()
        });

    });
```

Comment: This was 100% what I was after, thank-you so much - You completely fixed my noob mistakes :)
Perfectly explained, well laid out, and easy to read - Have a wonderful day/night where ever you are.

Answer (score 3):

[You can use this](http://jsfiddle.net/DzYTZ/5/)

```
$('.footer2').click(function() {
    var display=$('.footer2 .more').css('display') == 'inline' ? 'none' : 'inline'; 
    $('.footer2 .more').css('display', display);
});
```

Also remove the `display:inline` from the `footer2 .more{...}` to keep it initially hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `.footer .more` where I think you meant `.footer2 .more`. You will also need to hide `.more` with javascript, since you cannot have the css property `display` set to both `none` and `inline`. Finally I added a statement to toggle the 'Contact Us' text, but you can remove that if you want.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.footer2 .more').hide();

    $('.footer2').click(function() {
        $('.footer2 .more').toggle();
        $('.footer2 .contactus').toggle();
    });

});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/mG5EY/

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try and answer your question with an example that simply toggles a css class on the container to show and hide the contained elements:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="toggle-details" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <div class="details">Details</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.details-visible .toggle-details {
    display: none;
}
.details {
  display: none;   
}
.details-visible .details {
    display: block;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.toggle-details, .details').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.container').toggleClass('details-visible');
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PKHFH/)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, this is what you want [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DzYTZ/6/).
I took your fiddle and made some changes.

```
    $('.contactus').click(function() {
        if($(".more").css("display") == "none"){
            $(".more").css("display","inline");
        }else{            
            $(".more").css("display","none");
        }
    });
```

When you click on the Contact Us, it will hide the `more` class and if its already hidden then it will make it visible.
I just when along with the fiddle but I think you wanted the `more` class to be hidden by default so you can add this line before the code above.
`$(".more").css("display","none");`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this its works !**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```